# Can I reform this to a tensor/matrix product?

Tags: matrices, tensor-products

so I have the following vector matrix product:
$$v = A w$$
Now I have this $n$-times:
$$v^{(n)} = A^{(n)} w^{(n)} \quad \forall n$$
Is there any way to write this without $\forall$. Maybe somthing like this:
$$V = B W$$
where as the columns of $V$ are $v^{(n)}$ and the columns of $W$ are $w^{(n)}$.Then $B$ must be a 3 dimensional object. What is the correct name for it? Is it a rank 3 tensor? If yes, what tensor exactly?

Follow up: Lets say $A$ is column normalized. What is B called? Is there any smooth way to express this?

I hope the question makes sense. Thanks in advance,
Sascha

Comment: Is each $A^{(n)} $ distinct?

Comment: Yes, each $A^{(n)}$ is distinct. However an answer for $A^{(n)} = A^{(m)} \forall n,m$ would be interesting too.

Comment: when $A^{(n)} = A$, we can just take $V = AW$

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry, it was a long day. So anybody on $A^{(n)}$ being distinct?